# discharged with something

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does ***"discharged with casual ease"*** mean "lacking casual ease"?

> Context:
>
> These often aphoristic observations, discharged with casual ease, can
>   verge on possessing the lyrical poignancy and economy of a poet.

Comment: In the example sentence, _discharged_ means "performed", "made," or "done." It's the same sense of _discharged_ that Snout uses in _A Midsummer Night's Dream_, when he says, "Thus have I, Wall, my part discharged so;/And, being done, thus Wall away doth go."

Answer (score 1):

*Discharged* would normally carry the meaning of "carried out, performed, executed", as in "he discharged his duties with honour". From there, it slides into "his duties were complete and he could stand down", as in discharge from the military.

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/discharged?s=t)

In your example, his observations were thus simply carried out - made, performed, executed - with casual ease. He did them with no great effort.

Answer (score 0):

The antecedent sentence sets the meaning of the quoted phrase. "*Discharged...*" in this instance means spoken easily or entertainingly in the sense of 'tossed out' or 'off the cuff' or more formally [extemporaneous](//www.thefreedictionary.com/extemporaneous) or  [impromptu](//www.thefreedictionary.com/impromptu) speech.

> "...An alternative tour guide, pausing at intervals to regale his
>   audience with unknown pearls of walking wisdom.
>
> These often aphoristic observations, discharged with casual ease..."

quote from: Google Books: *Art and the City* By Nicholas Whybrow